# Extending a Future and/or preserving await functionality

Tags: dart, async-await, future

I'd like to extend the Future class and give it more functionality while keeping the functionality of the `await` keyword. As I understand it, Futures can't be extended directly in Dart, but perhaps there is another way to achieve what I want?

The class I'm trying to create is effectively a mechanism for interacting with an API. The server is RPC-like in the sense that its' API can be bi-directional while the request is open (messages can go back and forth between server and client until the request is considered resolved).

To make the client library more usable, I'm trying to create a Request class that has all the goodness of a normal Future, but also the ability to use a `when()` or `on()` function which effectively listens for updates during the resolution of the future.

Some sudo code of usage:

```dart
Request(args)
  .when('SomeEvent', (event) => print('An update: $event'))
  .then((response) => print('The final response: $response'))
  .onError((err) => print('Some error: $err'));

// This also needs to work:

final response = await Request(args);
```

So far I have something like this, but the `await` keyword doesn't work:

```dart
class Request {
  final Completer _completer = Completer();

  Request(args) {
    /* Setup and make some request to an API and respond/update using response|error|update */
  }

  Future<dynamic> then(fn) async {
    // Should this actually return a Request?
    return _completer.future.then(fn);
  }

  Future<dynamic> onError(fn) async {
    // Should this actually return a Request?
    return _completer.future.onError(fn);
  }

  Request when(String eventName, Function fn) {
    /* attach a listener/stream which fires fn on update */
    return this;
  }

  void _response(res) {
    _completer.complete(res);
  }

  void _error(err) {
    _completer.completeError(err);
  }

  void _update(upd) {
    /* Some update from the request is given */
  }
}
```

Is what I'm attempting impossible in Dart?

Comment: You can open dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart and check the implementation for the Future. But what is the main purpose do this? If I correctly understood you, you want to create the Future that can partially behave like a Stream, but Stream and Future have different lifecycles. Future returns one result, but Stream may produce one or more results while you are listening to it.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that I’m creating a client-facing library and trying to abstract away some of the complexity of streams. Users may or may not be interested in “updates” so having it behave more like a Future made sense to me.

Comment: @shennan I don't really understand how this "Super" future should work since you are talking about future which only have one value. But you want to have it simulate the possibility of multiple values. But how should code behave which expect it to behave like a normal future? It sounds more like you want to create a class which packs a `Stream` inside and haves a method that returns a `Future` which completes with the last value of the the `Stream` when it closes?

Comment: Correct. I want to leverage the usability of ‘await’ while allowing for the flexibility of a stream. It’s a client-facing library and the clients will be varied in their approach to interacting with it. The SuperFuture will still resolve to only one value, but will provide updates between instantiation and completion. Obviously these things could be done with separate methods attached to the class, but top of my xmas list is to have the functionality chain together in the way I have described in my OP. My hunch is that I’m getting push-back because it can’t be done. Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain a little more about the use-case. I may have confused the situation by calling the class a "SuperFuture". Really the class is a Request class that _acts_ as both a Future and stream.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not extending the `Future` interface, but instead let your `Request` class *have* a future instead of *being* a future.

Then you can do `await request.result` and `request.when(...)`, without having to re-implement the entire `Future` API.

If you insist on making `Request` be a `Future`, all you need is to add `implements Future<Object?>` to the class ... and then actually implement the entire `Future` API. No need to do `onError` (that's an extension method which works on any `Future`, including your `Request`), but you need to implement `then`, `catchError`, `whenComplete`, `asStream` and `timeout` correctly and totally (support all the arguments and have the correct type).
Then you'll be able to use your class with `await`.

If you do that, you *can* make those functions return `Request` too, if you make `Request` generic (`class Request<T> implements Future<T>`), because `.then<int>(...)` needs to return a `Future<int>`. You'd need a strategy for forwarding the `when`/`on` events to the new futures then.

It's much easier *not* to do that, and just expose the internal future by itself, separately from the progress callbacks.

See also [`CancelableOperation`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableOperation-class.html).